# How to remove old binary files in the installation dir using cmake?

Tags: makefile, cmake, installation

I am using `cmake` to build and install my C++ application. I have a custom install directory set by:

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX /home/user/release/myproj)
```

and I use `make install` to install the binaries and libraries to this custom install location. Is there a way to clean the destination directory every time I call `make install` to clean up possible old binaries in this installation dir?

Comment: You may use `install(CODE)` or `install(SCRIPT)` for add actions for installation process. Place this call in the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` before any other `install()` calls, so additional actions will be performed before installing any file. However, more clear solution would be removing install directory before `make install` or running `make uninstall` manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove files using the `file` command in cmake. Here is an example to remove old binaries, just define `EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH`:

```
    file(GLOB MY_FILES  ${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}/*)
    if (MY_FILES)
        file (REMOVE ${MY_FILES})
    endif()
```